# Framerate and game loop on mobile

Tags: android, ios, game-loop, frame-rate, timestep

I'm searching how to manage game framerate on mobiles devices, here is my problem:

**On a computer with got something like that:**

```
void main()
{
    while(game.isRunning())
    {
        event.handle(eventInfos);
        game.update(dt);
        graphic.render();
    }
}
```

**On a mobile device with got something like that:**

```
void update()
{
    game.update(dt);
}

void render()
{
    game.render(dt);
}

void event()
{
    game.handle(eventInfos);
}
```

When I search on internet, I found something like that everytime:

[-> GameLoop](http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/)

[-> Fix your time step](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

I'm using IOS (With GLKViewController) and Android (with the NDK), and I've that rendering method is call from another thread

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The structure of the update/render functions is unrelated to desktop/mobile. For example, with [love2d the render function is a callback too](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/Tutorial:Callback_Functions). The key difference is that for mobile you avoid drawing if nothing has changed, as battery life is at a premium.

Answer (score 1):

To get the right amount of movement when using a update(dt) function you must multiply the movement speed against delta time (dt = the amount of time since last frame update). So your position update could look like: newPosition = oldPosition + (moveSpeed * dt)

I hope this helps, I dont really understand what you mean by 'manage framerate'.